# Postfix rejecting mail when milter is down - is it possible to let the emails throu anyway?

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, milter

I am running a emailserver with two milters:

OpenDMARC and OpenARC - both has worked very well and has been stable. I have defined both milters like this:

```
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8893,inet:localhost:8991
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8893,inet:localhost:8991
```

When I turn off one of the milters (for example OpenDMARC), all the incoming emails is rejected (as expected).

Is it possible to tell postfix to still deliver the emails even if the milters is down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is yes, with the option "`milter_default_action = accept`".
I prefer to use "`milter_default_action = tempfail`", so the mail will come back later, in case of milter failure.

http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#errors